# Get single property of array Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, variables

i tried many ways, but i don't have any clue how to get a single property of an array.

I want to make this
Array1:

```
 this.array1 = [{name: 'misko', gender: 'male'},{name: 'misko', gender: 'male'}];
```

And then i want to get only names from array 1 to an array but how like

```
     this.array2 = [{'misko'},{'misko'}];
```

my code

```
        this.getList = function() {

        this.timesheets = Timesheets.query({
            projectId: $scope.selected.project[0],
            startWeek: this.weekStart,
            endWeek: this.weekEnd
        });
        $log.log('1');
        this.timesheetsId = this.timesheets.map(function (el) {
            return { name: el._id };
            $log.log('2');
        });

    };
```

i can see log 1 in console not log2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), like this

```
this.array1 = [{name: 'misko', gender: 'male'},{name: 'misko', gender: 'male'}];

this.array2 = this.array1.map(function (el) {
   return { name: el.name };
})
```

Comment: @Stweet is Timesheets.query async function, you need put your code to success callback

Comment: Arhhh now i understand, awesome ! Thx mate